# vba, each result for key word in a new row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro,wrote in vba

```
Sub SumByKeyWords()

    ' Define variables for Workbook1 and Workbook2
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    ' Set references to the two workbooks
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("forcast.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("kesz4.xlsm")
    ' Define array of keywords to search for
    Dim keywords As Variant
    keywords = Array("Hamburg", "Berlin", "Munich")
    Dim destRange As Range
    ' Set the destination range to the first empty row in column A of Workbook2
    Set destRange = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    ' Loop through each keyword
    Dim keyword As Variant
    For Each keyword In keywords
        ' Check if the keyword is found in column A of Workbook1
        Dim keywordRow As Variant
        keywordRow = Application.Match(keyword, wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"), 0)
        If IsNumeric(keywordRow) Then
            ' Loop through each column in the source range (excluding column A)
            Dim colIndex As Integer
            For colIndex = 2 To 6
                ' Get the sum of the three rows and place it in the destination workbook
                Dim sumValue As Variant
                sumValue = Application.Sum(wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(keywordRow, colIndex), wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(keywordRow + 2, colIndex)))
                destRange.Value = sumValue
                ' Move the destination range to the next cell in the same row
                Set destRange = destRange.Offset(0, 1)
            Next colIndex
        End If
    Next keyword
    
End Sub
```

It search for key words in one workbook and set the result(sum of columns) in an other. I need the results in a new row for each city because now it looks like this: [image]

They are the sum of Hamburg from 1 to 5(the first 5) and the result for Berlin from 1 to 9. I need the result like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Match & Sumup

- Use the first cell with `Offset` to fill the row, and use `Offset` to reference the next first cell (the cell below):

  ```
          destRange.Offset(, colIndex - 2).Value = sumValue
      Next colIndex
      Set destRange = destRange.Offset(1)
  End If
  ```

```vb
Sub SumByKeyWords()
    
    ' Constants

    Dim KeyWords As Variant: KeyWords = Array("Hamburg", "Berlin", "Munich")
    
    ' Source (Read From)
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks("Forcast.xlsx")
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:A10")
    
    ' Destination (Write To)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("Kesz4.xlsm")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    ' Loop.
    
    Dim KeyWord, srIndex, sc As Long
    
    For Each KeyWord In KeyWords
        srIndex = Application.Match(KeyWord, srg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(srIndex) Then
            For sc = 2 To 6
                ' the same cell with an offset
                dfCell.Offset(, sc - 2).Value _
                    = Application.Sum(sws.Cells(srIndex, sc).Resize(3))
            Next sc
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1) ' the cell below (next city)
        End If
    Next KeyWord
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Sums by keywords retrieved.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that's the solution which I want, thank you !